# WPF problems refreshing textblock bound to console.stdout

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, console, refresh

I am building a small wpf app in C#. When a button gets clicked a third 
party dll function constructs a tree like object. This object is bound 
to a treeview. This works fine but takes a bit of time to load. As the 
dll function constructs the object it prints progress info to the 
console. I want to redirect this into a TextBlock so that the user 
gets to see the progress messages.

My window ctor looks like this:

```
InitializeComponent(); 
StringRedir s = new StringRedir(ref ProgressTextBlock); 
Console.SetOut(s); 
Console.SetError(s); 
this.DataContext = s;
```

xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text}" Width="244" 
x:Name="ProgressTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap"  /> 
<TreeView >...</TreeView>
```

The StringRedir class is shown below. The problem is the TextBlock for 
some reason does not get updated with the messages until the TreeView 
gets loaded. Stepping through I see the Text property being updated 
but the TextBlock is not getting refreshed. I added a MessageBox.Show 
() at the point where Text gets updated and this seems to cause the 
window to refresh each time and I am able to see each message. So I 
guess I need some way to explicitly refresh the screen...but this 
doesnt make sense I thought the databinding would cause a visual 
refresh when the property changed. What am I missing here? How do I 
get it to refresh? Any advice is appreciated!

```
public class StringRedir : StringWriter , INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ 
    private string text; 
    private TextBlock local; 


    public string Text { 
        get{ return text;} 
        set{ 
            text = text + value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Text"); 
        } 
    } 


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name) 
    { 
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged; 
        if (handler != null) 
        { 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)); 
        } 
    } 


    public StringRedir(ref TextBlock t) 
    { 
        local = t; 
        Text = ""; 
    } 


    public override void WriteLine(string x) 
    { 
        Text = x +"\n"; 
        //MessageBox.Show("hello"); 
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included the code that is loading the data for the `TreeView`, but I'm guessing it's being done on the UI thread. If so, this will block any UI updates (including changes to the `TextBlock`) until it has completed.

Comment: Using the 2008 express edition, doesnt have the debug threads window. I know the TextBlock.Text is updated (it is firing the TargetUpdated event). I just need it to redraw itself. Tried all the invalidate methods but it seems like they are async or possibly low priority. Need a way to force redraw

Comment: If you want to process all UI messages from the UI thread, check out my post here: http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/04/dispatcher-frames.html. It will show you how to implement DoEvents() in WPF. Call that after you set the text and you should be fine.

Comment: Ha! what timing I just posted an answer involving Dispatcher Invoke. Will check out your post. Thanks for the help. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So after doing some reading on the WPF threading model ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx ) I finally got it to refresh by calling Dispatcher Invoke() with Dispatch priority set to Render. As Kent suggested above UI updates in the dispatcher queue were probably low priority. I ended up doing something like this.

XAML

```
<TextBox VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  
         Text="{Binding Path=Text, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
         x:Name="test" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" 
         TargetUpdated="test_TargetUpdated"/>
```

C# target updated handler code

```
private void test_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
    t.ScrollToEnd();
    t.Dispatcher.Invoke(new EmptyDelegate(() => { }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render);
}
```

Note: Earlier I was using a TextBlock but I changed to a TextBox as it comes with scrolling

I still feel uneasy about the whole flow though. Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks to Matt and Kent for their comments. If I had points would mark their answers as helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the constructor of your StringRedir class. You're passing in ProgessTextBlock, and you're doing this to it:

```
local.Text = "";
```

This is effectively *overwriting* the previously set value for ProgressTextBlock.Text, which was this:

```
{Binding Text}
```

See what I mean? By explicitly setting a value to the TextBlock's Text property, you've cancelled the binding.

If I'm reading right, it looks like the idea of passing a TextBlock into the StringRedir's ctor is a hangover from before you tried binding directly. I'd ditch that and stick with the binding idea as it's more in the "spirit" of WPF.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Okay...that made me actually think about what I was doing with databinding :) The StringRedir class code, I found on msdn and blindly assummed I needed the local TextBlock reference to pass text back. Wow data binding...so thats what it does :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it does indeed fix the problem.

Comment: Will definately do that. But I am still not seeing the textblock refresh (It does only once the entire treeview gets loaded). I have removed the local TextBlock from the StringRedir class and am just relying on binding now.